# Centering in tabularx and X columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

How can I center the column when using X in tabularx environment like in this example?

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXXXXX@{}}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\   
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: do you want to centre an entire column or just one row, or just one cell?

Comment: Sorry... I want to center all X columns

Comment: Use `c` instead of `X`.

Comment: Please consider taking Huugo as the correct answer.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present my solution: I defined a new columntype `Y` to center the cells in a `tabularx`environment.

In the preamble define:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

to typeset the example simply enter

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lYYYYY@{}}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\   
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Would it be on topic to expand this answer to how to center a specific row? (if there is such an elegant solution to do so)

Comment: In my case this solution does not affect the last column, where the content is left-alighed.

Answer (score 41):

You have two solutions (well at least)

If you are bound to `tabularx` then you can use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l *5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\end{tabularx}
```

Alternatively you can use the `tabu` package which offers you a lot more flexibility:

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {@{} l *5{X[c]}@{}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\end{tabu}
```

Comment: how to do the tabularx for \ruggedright? just replacing centering doesnt work :(

Comment: @ankhi probably because it is spelt `\raggedright`! However, a solution to this question (and this really should be a separate question rather than a comment to a vaguely related one), is given in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175238/12332) which uses the same package as suggested by herbert below

Comment: May I ask what the `@{}` is doing?

Comment: @Raven have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/clarification-on-the-use-of-with-table-headings). Basically it removes spaces.

Answer (score 20):

```
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
```

with `ragged2e` you do not need the `\arraybackslash`

Answer (score 4):

It’s easy peasy to set cell alignment with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {@{}X[c]X[l]X[c]X[r]X[c]@{}},
  hlines, vlines,
}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\   
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great indeed. LaTeX3 rocks!