# How to center text in tabularx?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166/centering-in-tabularx-and-x-columns)

I was using `\begin{tabular}` to insert a table in my article. The titles for columns were long which caused the table to extend out across the paper boundary. I searched online and found that `{tabularx}` will wrap the text. I used it which solved the problem. But I want my content to be centered. How do I achieve this in the `{tabularx}` environment? I am new to LaTeX and this is my first article. I have copied my script below:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Clear Zone Deficiency and Crash Severity} 
\centering 
\begin{tabularx} {\linewidth} {X X X X X X X}
\hline\hline       
CLEAR ZONE DEFICIENCY & TOTAL CRASHES & FATAL & INJURY & PDO & \% CRASHES & \% FATAL \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline           
0ft-4ft & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7.84 & 0 \\ 
4ft-8ft & 14 & \textbf{1} & 4 & 9 & 27.45 & 9.09 \\
8ft-12ft & 15 & \textbf{1} & 5 & 9 & 29.41 & 9.09 \\ 
12ft + & 18 & \textbf{9} & 4 & 5 & 35.29 & \textbf{81.82}\\
\hline
TOTAL & 51 & 11 & 15 & 25 & 100 & 100 \\ [1ex]     
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:CZseverity} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: If you do want to use tx rather than ty then replace each `X` by `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X`

Answer (score 8):

If you use the `tabulary` instead, and then use `C` instead of `X`, it will automatically adjust the table widths and center the contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary} % instead of tabularx

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Clear Zone Deficiency and Crash Severity} 
\centering 
\begin{tabulary} {\linewidth} {C C C C C C C}
\hline\hline       
CLEAR ZONE DEFICIENCY & TOTAL CRASHES & FATAL & INJURY & PDO & \% CRASHES & \% FATAL \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline           
0ft-4ft & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7.84 & 0 \\ 
4ft-8ft & 14 & \textbf{1} & 4 & 9 & 27.45 & 9.09 \\
8ft-12ft & 15 & \textbf{1} & 5 & 9 & 29.41 & 9.09 \\ 
12ft + & 18 & \textbf{9} & 4 & 5 & 35.29 & \textbf{81.82}\\
\hline
TOTAL & 51 & 11 & 15 & 25 & 100 & 100 \\ [1ex]     
\hline 
\end{tabulary}
\label{table:CZseverity} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you find some of your titles have unnecessary broken words and you don't need word wrapping in those columns, just use `c` instead of `C`.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest several changes:

- I would load the package `{booktabs}` and use it's `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`.
- Instead of `0ft-4ft` you should `0\,ft--4\,ft` (thin space between value and unit, n-dash instead of hyphen).
- You can pass `\centering\arraybackslash` to the column `X` by saying `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X`, the shortcut `*{n}{spec}` repeats column specification `spec` exactly `n` times.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Clear Zone Deficiency and Crash Severity} 
\centering 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
CLEAR ZONE DEFICIENCY & TOTAL CRASHES & FATAL & INJURY & PDO & \% CRASHES & \% FATAL \\ [0.5ex] 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]         
0\,ft--4\,ft & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7.84 & 0 \\ 
4\,ft--8\,ft & 14 & \textbf{1} & 4 & 9 & 27.45 & 9.09 \\
8\,ft--12\,ft & 15 & \textbf{1} & 5 & 9 & 29.41 & 9.09 \\ 
$>{}$12\,ft & 18 & \textbf{9} & 4 & 5 & 35.29 & \textbf{81.82}\\
\midrule
TOTAL & 51 & 11 & 15 & 25 & 100 & 100 \\ [1ex]     
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:CZseverity} 
\end{table}
```