# table - text centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I made a table in my thesis with this code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{cc}
    \toprule
    & Folhosas \\
    \midrule
    Celulose & 5 \\
    Hemicelulose & 2 \\
    Extrac & 6 \\
    Lenhinha & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
```

But, I want the text in the middle of table.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please always post complete documents (as in the answer supplied).

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please provide more information. If my answer is what you want, this question is a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89166 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91060

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    & Folhosas \\
    \midrule
    Celulose & 5 \\
    Hemicelulose & 2 \\
    Extrac & 6 \\
    Lenhinha & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you may want to take a look on the package `tabulary` and its `C` column.