# Wrap text in table column header AND fit table width to pagewidth

Tags: tabularx

How do I get a table where the header in column 2 is wrapped, while keeping the width of the table = textwidth? As you can see from the attached figure, I have a long title for the 2nd column, which makes the column very wide, resulting in wrapping of the text (actual entries, not the title) in the first column. I guess in a more general sense, I want to prioritize wrapping of column titles over wrapping of actual column entries. (I am not stuck on using tabularx; I am happy to try any other package if it works.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx}                                                                                           \\ \hline
\textbf{miRNA}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{logFC (ABCDEF vs ABCFED)}} & \textbf{PValue} & \textbf{False Discovery Rate}    \\ \hline
abcd efg hijka  & -1.854                                                & 9.52E-11        & 8.41E-10                         \\
abcd efg hijka  & -1.815                                                & 3.38E-09        & 2.42E-08                         \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width

\end{document}
```

[image: what I get now]

Comment: Remove the `\multicolumn{1}` for the header in the second column.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really understand why that was there, http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ produced that table. Teaches me not to use code without understanding.

Comment: also don't use `[h]` on its own (latex normamly issues a warning and changes it to `[ht]` but better to use `[htp]` to give latex a chance not to take the float to the end of the document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `makecell` package that enables pre-formatting of column heads and multine heads. I also used the `booktabs` package to have better-looking horizontal rules and a less tight vertical spacing. Finally `numprint` allows for scientific notations in cells.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}
\usepackage[autolanguage, np]{numprint}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{Z}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx}   \\
\midrule
\thead{miRNA}  & \thead{logFC \\ (ABCDEF vs \\ ABCFED) } & \thead{PValue} & \thead{False \\Discovery\\ Rate} \\%
\midrule
abcd efg hijka  & $-1.854$                                                & \np{9.52E-11}        & \np{8.41E-10}                         \\
abcd efg hijka  & $-1.815$                                                & \np{3.38E-09}        & \np{2.42E-08}                         \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks beautiful. Quick clarification: can I just use '\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{Z}}' instead of \begin{tabularx}'{\textwidth}{*{4}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}Z}}' as they both seem to do the same thing? Maybe you meant to write '\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}' there? Also, numprint is awesome!

Comment: Yes you can. I mistyped the new column type definition. I'll correct it at once.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `siunitx` and `tabular*` instead of `tabularx`, because you're so able to get perfect output for the numbers. The first example is how you can do with `tabularx`, but note that you would have to manually correct the input for numbers. With the `siunitx` approach you can just input numbers as they are.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\tabheader}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx} \\
\hline
\textbf{miRNA}  & 
  \textbf{logFC (ABCDEF vs ABCFED)} & 
  \textbf{PValue} & 
  \textbf{False Discovery Rate} \\
\hline
abcd efg hijka  & -1.854 & 9.52E-11 & 8.41E-10 \\
abcd efg hijka  & -1.815 & 3.38E-09 & 2.42E-08 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\sisetup{
  exponent-product={},
  output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}},
}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=1.2E-2]
  S[table-format=1.2E-2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx} \\
\midrule
\tabheader{miRNA}  & 
  \tabheader{logFC (ABCDEF\\ vs ABCFED)} & 
  \tabheader{PValue} & 
  \tabheader{False\\ Discovery\\ Rate} \\
\midrule
abcd efg hijka  & -1.854 & 9.52E-11 & 8.41E-10 \\
abcd efg hijka  & -1.815 & 3.38E-09 & 2.42E-08 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `X` columns only if needed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} 
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lXlX @{} }\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx} \\ \hline
\textbf{miRNA}  & \textbf{logFC (ABCDEF vs ABCFED)} & \textbf{PValue} & \textbf{False Discovery Rate}    \\ \hline
abcd efg hijka  & -1.854                                                & 9.52E-11        & 8.41E-10                         \\
abcd efg hijka  & -1.815                                                & 3.38E-09        & 2.42E-08                         \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width

\end{document}
```

[image]