# Left-align data in first column of table and not in header

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using the following code to format my tables for my thesis (template based on this question here: [Wrap text in table column header AND fit table width to pagewidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175223/wrap-text-in-table-column-header-and-fit-table-width-to-pagewidth)

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}
\usepackage[autolanguage, np]{numprint}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{Z}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx}   \\
\midrule
\thead{miRNA}  & \thead{logFC \\ (ABCDEF vs \\ ABCFED) } & \thead{PValue} & \thead{False \\Discovery\\ Rate} \\%
\midrule
abcd efg hijka  & $-1.854$                                                & \np{9.52E-11}        & \np{8.41E-10}                         \\
abcd efg hijka  & $-1.815$                                                & \np{3.38E-09}        & \np{2.42E-08}                         \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width a lot of text here to show text width

\end{document}
```

[image]
I was wondering how can I left align only the data in the first column of this table? Is there an easy way to maybe change the `\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }` command to only leftalign data in the first column of the table and not the header? The other columns and headers should remain centered.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Declare the first column as `l` and input the header with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Header}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X*{3}{Z}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{xxx xx xxxx}   \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
\thead{miRNA}  & \thead{logFC \\ (ABCDEF vs \\ ABCFED) } & \thead{PValue} & \thead{False \\Discovery\\ Rate} \\%
\midrule
abcd efg hijka  & $-1.854$                                                & \np{9.52E-11}        & \np{8.41E-10}                         \\
abcd efg hijka  & $-1.815$                                                & \np{3.38E-09}        & \np{2.42E-08}                         \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

since an `X`column, by default, is left-aligned, but `\thead` is centred (vertically and horizontally).

Additionally, I think `\cmidrule(lr){1-4}` between the first two rows will look nicer than `\midrule`.