# How to change tabularx 'X' command to raggedRight

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to use the X command from tabular X to evenly space a tables columns. However, the individual comulns are quite narrow, and this makes the justified spacing look really bad.

Is there anyway to force the X command to be raggedRight instead of justified? I think I could do this on a cell by cell basis, but I have a massive table, and I dont want to do this for every cell. So, is there an alternate command, or some way of creating a new command which would keep the columns spaced evenly, but ragged right?

Comment: `\usepackage{array}\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}` and then using `R` column should do the trick.

Comment: This question is similar to [Centering in `tabularx` and `X` columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89166/5764). You can use `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`, or define a new column type altogether so and use that column instead of `X`.

Comment: Regarding `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X`, see section 4.2 of the `tabularx` documentation.

Comment: You could load the `ragged2e` package (in addition to the `tabularx` package) and define `\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}`. That way, hyphenation is enabled for the material in the `R` columns, which makes for less-ragged-looking appearance.

Comment: @yo' - The `tabularx` package loads the `array` package -- need to load `array` explicitly. :-)