# tabularx: Cell With Manual Line Breaks | Problem With Vertical Line

Tags: tabularx

When I have a **manual line break** in a cell of a `tabularx` table, then the vertical line goes missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
\hline
% Row
Text & & & & & & \\ \hline
% Row
Text\\ Text & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Related

- [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441)

Comment: problem is in this line: `Text\\ Text & & & & & & \\ \hline` if the firs text is own row (in `l` column type only this is sensible, since it is not designe for multline contents)than it should follows ampersands for each empty cell.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. So the `\\\` isn't "allowed" with in a cell?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Many column specific stuff does require the column to be existent. It's the same with e.g. `\rowcolor`, which also only colors the cells which are existent. If you end a line in a `tabular` the remaining cells are non existent to those formattings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the comment above. `\\ ` ends the row so that row only has one cell. The vertical lines are all the right hand content of a cell (except the first cell which has left and right rules) so if you omit the cell the line goes, just as if you omit it with `\multicolumn`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the explanation. I guess I am too tired to think straight. I should have known that \\ ends the row. I tried to search the problem. Apparently I didn't use the right terms.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, directly in cell no, as you see from other comments and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want line breaks in one of the `l, c, r` column types, you have to load  `makecell` package and use its eponymous command. Otherwise, `\\` is taken as a row change. With this code, it's fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
\hline
% Row
Text & & & & & & \\ \hline
% Row
\makecell[l]{Text\\ Text} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another possibility is the use of `\pbox`.

Comment: Thanks. The `makecell` package seems to be very useful. Some of my last table-related questions were solved by using it.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks. I'll upvote if you provide an answer (probably not today...going to bed).

Answer (score 1):

You can always put boxes in tables in which `\\` doesn't end the table row. One handy command is `\pbox` as it doesn't use more space than necessary but has a maximum width. Unfortunately, the vertical spacing doesn't fit with just `\pbox`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
\hline
% Row
Text & & & & & & \\ \hline
% Row
\pbox{\textwidth}{Text\\ Text} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: results]

One can clearly see, that the vertical spacing isn't right in the above image.