# Make a format for AUN programme by LaTex?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I am writing the AUN (Asean University Network) format for my university like that. However, I do not know make the status like "University of HongKong", "Department of Telecommunication" etc at the center of part, and  the 3 tables like that?

Below is my entire code for an as table example as I managed to create:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.0cm, bmargin=1.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{fullpage}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,latexsym, amssymb, amscd}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}
\usepackage{tabu}


\begin{document}
%Header-Make sure you update this information!!!!
\noindent
\large\textbf{UNIVERSITY OF HONGKONG} \hfill \textbf{DEPARTMENT OF TELECOMMUNICATION} \\
\normalsize FACULTY OF ELECTRICAL \& ELECTRONICS ENGINEERING \hfill Independence – Freedom – Happiness
 \\
\hfill HongKong city, ………………………………

\begin{center}
\section*{ COURSE SYLLABUS}
\subsection*{DIGITAL IMAGE PROCESSING}
\subsection*{Course code: 402084}
\end{center}



\section{Information} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
\hline
No. of credits & 2(2,0)  \\
% \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Time allocation} & Theory (hours) & 45 & Practice (hours) & 0 & Self-study (hours) & 90 \\
\hline
Prior-completion & N/A  \\
\hline
Co-requisite  & Digital Signal Processing  \\
\hline
Programme & Bachelor in Electronics and Telecommunications Engineering
  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\section{Course objectives (COs)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
\hline
No.   & Course Outcomes (COs) & Expected Learning Outcomes (ELOs)  \\
\hline
1 & Understand the about Digital Image Processing: applications digital image processing, basic steps in digital image processing. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
2  & Understand how to design digital image processing algorithms. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
3 & Understand the about Digital Image Processing: applications digital image processing, basic steps in digital image processing. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
3 & Understand the about Digital Image Processing: applications digital image processing, basic steps in digital image processing. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

\end{document}

[image: The first and second figure]

[image: The third]

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with `biblatex`, so I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have center-aligned the heading and edited the tables.

I used the [multicolumn package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and the [tabularx package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), which allows to table columns with varying widths (specified with an `X`).
To center align these columns, I have defined a new column specifier `Y` which does the same as `X` but center aligns them. This was taken from [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166/centering-in-tabularx-and-x-columns).

Furthermore, I have deleted all packages that were not used. You can reinsert them, as required. I have added the `\MakeUppercase` command for upper case text.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.0cm, bmargin=1.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % to center the columns

\begin{document}


% Header - Make sure you update this information!!!!
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXc}
\large\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Your University}} & & \textbf{Your department} \\ % University and faculty are converted to UPPER case
\normalsize \MakeUppercase{Your Faculty} & & Independence – Freedom – Happiness \\
& & HongKong city, ………………………………
\end{tabularx}


\begin{center}
\section*{ \MakeUppercase{Course Syllabus}}
\subsection*{\MakeUppercase{Digital Image Processing}}
\subsection*{Course code: 402084}
\end{center}

\section{Information} 


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|Y|X|Y|l|l|} 
\hline
\textbf{No. of credits} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{2(2,0)}  \\
\hline
\textbf{Time allocation} & Theory (hours) & 45 & Practice (hours) & 0 & Self-study (hours) & 90 \\
\hline
\textbf{Prior-completion} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Digital Signal Processing} & \textbf{Prior-completion code} & 402070\\
\hline
\textbf{Co-requisite}  & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{N/A}  & \textbf{Co-requisite code }& N/A\\
\hline
\textbf{Programme} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Bachelor in Electronics and Telecommunications Engineering} & \textbf{Programme Code} & 700000\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}


\section{Course objectives (COs)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|} 
\hline
\textbf{No.}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Course Outcomes (COs)}} & \textbf{Expected Learning Outcomes (ELOs)}  \\
\hline
1 & Understand the about Digital Image Processing: applications digital image processing, basic steps in digital image processing. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
2  & Understand how to design digital image processing algorithms. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
3 & Understand the about Digital Image Processing: applications digital image processing, basic steps in digital image processing. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
3 & Understand the about Digital Image Processing: applications digital image processing, basic steps in digital image processing. & ELO 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

It produces this result:
[image]