# cells not centering after multicell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

I'm trying to create a tabular with all the cells centered. I have found a way to make this possible but all the cells have to contain:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{"Text"}
```

Is there a way to center the text without the need to add the multicolumn command everywhere?

[image: Tabular]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}    {|c|p{.7\textwidth/5}|p{.7\textwidth/5}|p{.7\textwidth/5}|p{.7\textwidth/5}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\backslashbox{Distance [m]}{Module}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Range Test [dBm]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Throughput Test [Kbps]}\\\cline{2-5}
   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A-B} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A-C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A-B} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A-C} \\\cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{•} & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{15} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{20} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{25} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{35} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{40} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{45} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{50} & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

when I try and use only centered cells I get the issue that the cells are not equally sized.
[image: table centered]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/35864 can help you. The accepted answer shows how to define fixed-width (like `p{...}`) centred (like `c`) columns.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The point is that I would rather not hardcode the size of the cells and keep this variable.

Comment: Currently you are hard-coding the size with `p{.7\textwidth/5}`, so I thought that is what you are after. If you want automatic sizing you may want to look into `tabularx` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89166/35864) or `tabulary`.

Comment: Yes when i remove that and exchange it with 'c' I get the issue that the cells aren't distributed evenly.

Comment: The question I linked (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/35864) shows how to define fixed-width centred columns. You would have `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}` and would then use `C{.7\textwidth/5}` instead of `p{.7\textwidth/5}` or `c`.

Comment: So you mean that I either have to choose between having a fixed size with center or a non defined size without center?

Comment: No, I'm saying if you follow the link (or use the code I reproduced in my comment above) you don't have to choose, you can have both. (It is just not available out of the box.)

Answer (score 2):

Here a much shorter code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular} {|c|*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.7\textwidth/5}|}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox[height=\dimexpr2\line +6pt]{Distance \rlap{{[m]}}}{Module}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Range Test [dBm]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Throughput Test [Kbps]}\\[2pt]\cline{2-5}
   & A-B & A-C & A-B & A-C \\\cline{1-5}
10 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
15
 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
20 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
25 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
30 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
35 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
40 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
 45 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
50 & • & • & • & • \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}
 \usepackage{float}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{3cm}*{4}{w{c}{0.14\textwidth}}}[hvlines]
 \Block{2-1}{\diagbox{Distance [m]}{Module}} & \Block{1-2}{Range Test [dBm]} && \Block{1-2}{Throughput Test [Kbps]}\\
    & A-B & A-C & A-B & A-C \\
 10 & • & • & • & • \\
 15 & • & • & • & • \\
 20 & • & • & • & • \\
 25 & • & • & • & • \\
 30 & • & • & • & • \\
 35 & • & • & • & • \\
 40 & • & • & • & • \\
 45 & • & • & • & • \\
 50 & • & • & • & • \\
 \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

text in your columns is not centered since you prescribe `p{...}` column type. as mentioned in comments to your  question you should modify column type to:

```
>{\centerng\arraybackslash}p{<column width>}
```

However, I would not use `slashbox` for first cell in table and for table I would use `tabularx` table environment and equal width in all columns:

[image]

Also I would remove all unnecessary `multicolumns`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
%\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{| c | *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Module}            \\
    \cline{2-5}
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering  Distance [m]}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Range Test [dBm]}
                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Throughput Test [Kbps]}   \\
    \cline{2-5}
   &  A-B   &   A-C &   A-B & A-C        \\
   \cline{1-5}
10  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
15  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
20  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
25  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
30  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
35  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
40  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
45  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
50  &   •   &   •   &   •   & •         \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I copy your code and paste it in my working document I don't get the same results. I get the error " X Columns too narrow (table too wide)" it looks like the distance column is the size of the page and the others are slapped against it on the right.

Comment: @DylanBeijersbergen: You can try with `\multirow{3}{*}{\centering  Distance [m]} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Module}            \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Range Test [dBm]}`...

Comment: I get the error that the last cell on the right is slightly larger then the rest.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpJvo.png

Comment: @DylanBeijersbergen, to your preamble I only add the package `tabularx`. if your real document has different page layout, than it can happen, that table  has different size. try to increase the table environment width from `0.7\linewidth` to for example `0.75\linewidth` to even to `\linewidth`.