# I can't make the table organized and data in centered

Tags: tables, xetex

I am trying to organize the following table data centered and well-organized. Since I have very few knowledge in latex I am unable to organize the table. Please help. Thank you.

```
    \documentclass{nle}
\makeatletter
\let\O@argtabularcr\@argtabularcr
\def\O@xtabularcr{\@ifnextchar[\O@argtabularcr{\ifnum 0=`{\fi}\cr}}
\let\O@tabacol\@tabacol
\let\O@tabclassiv\@tabclassiv
\let\O@tabclassz\@tabclassz
\let\O@tabarray\@tabarray
\def\author@tabular{\authorsize\def\@halignto{}\@authortable}
\let\endauthor@tabular=\endtabular
\def\author@tabcrone{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\O@xtabularcr\affilsize\itshape
 \let\\=\author@tabcrtwo\ignorespaces}
\def\author@tabcrtwo{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\O@xtabularcr[-3\p@]\affilsize\itshape
 \let\\=\author@tabcrtwo\ignorespaces}
\def\@authortable{\leavevmode \hbox \bgroup $\let\@acol\O@tabacol
 \let\@classz\O@tabclassz \let\@classiv\O@tabclassiv
 \let\\=\author@tabcrone \ignorespaces \O@tabarray}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
% Reinsert missing \algbackskip
\def\algbackskip{\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Vrinda}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname={List of Diagrams},
    name=Diagram,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=none,
]{diagram}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] % <--- "here", "top", "bottom"
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Levenshtein’s distance between two words.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}
    \toprule
    \toprule
\makecell[lb]{Lexicon word}
            & \makecell[b]{Levenshtein’s distance with \\ misspelled word \textbengali{“বিদান”}} \\
    \midrule
\textbengali{দান} & 2  \\
\textbengali{বিধান} & 1  \\
\textbengali{অনুদান} & 3  \\

    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{table4}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JouleV Please check now.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89166/134144).