# How can I draw 2 separated lines in the same line, and write centered text below them?

Tags: spacing, graphics, horizontal-alignment, formatting

How can I draw 2 separated lines in the same line, and  write centered text  below them?

I tried with this code

```
\begin{flushleft}
\rule{7cm}{.01cm}

Name 1
\end{flushleft}

\hspace{1cm} 

\begin{flushright}
\rule{7cm}{.01cm}
Name 2
\end{flushright}
```

But the output was incorrect because

1. The lines were drawn in separated lines (and there was enough space to be drawn both in the same line)
2. The text below them wasn't centered but moved to the left and right, respectively

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A picture of the expected output might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand 100% what you're trying to achieve, but --- like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\rule{0.4\textwidth}{1pt} \hfill \rule{0.4\textwidth}{1pt} \\
Text
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what comes to my mind when I hear "two separated lines in the same line, and centered text below them" anyway.

**EDIT:**

Here's what I might do in order to put centered text under each line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Yp{1cm}Y}
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
Text 1 && Text 2
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

(The `Y` column type is taken from @Huugo's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932/158639).) Using `\cline` is probably suboptimal, and I'm sure there's more elegant, better-looking or just plain simpler ways of achieving this; I'm no TeXnician yet! But it might get you started.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Here's another version that uses `\hrulefill` (which I hadn't known about until now!) instead of `\cline`, and adds a little space between the two lines of the `tabular` environment by supplying the `\\`'s optional parameter --- one `ex`, to be precise, adjust this to your liking.

Speaking of spaces, the gap between the two lines is currently set to one centimeter, and this can also be adjusted. What's more, if you want to make the whole `tabular` narrower, you can change its width from `\textwidth` to `0.8\textwidth` or something along those lines. (You'll probably want to wrap it in a `center` environment again then, otherwise it'll be flush left.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Yp{1cm}Y}
\hrulefill&&\hrulefill\\[1ex]
Text 1 && Text 2
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Something like that, tho the text goes below the lines: text 1, text 2

Comment: Ah, I see. Give me a moment.

Comment: @Verónica how's this now?

Comment: Aha, that was the idea. Although with more space between the line and the text. Like if using `\begin{center}
\rule{7cm}{.01cm}
name
\end{center}`

Comment: @Verónica I made another edit --- see if this is what you need now!

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. For some reason the parameter [1ex] of \\ doesn't work to be reduced. Works to be expanded, I tried with 5 and separated the text from the line. I tried with .001ex but does nothing, it's like if it had 1ex. Also, doesn't match with the image that you display, that space is smaller than the one that I see.

Comment: @Verónica `[1ex]` means that one `ex` of extra space gets added. `0.001ex` is going to be about the same as nothing at all, i.e. `\\ ` without the optional parameter. You can pass negative values though, so perhaps try `\\[-1ex]` and go from there.

Comment: ahhh. Got it, it worked :) thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! :)