# How to delete the horizontal space between text and a line to-write-text-on?

Tags: spacing, formatting, tabularx, setspace

How  to delete the horizontal space between the text  and a line to write text on?

To clarify I'm referring to the space that comes after the ":" and that is before the line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}


    \noindent
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{Yp{-20cm}Y}
    name:&& name\\[-2ex]
    && \hrulefill \\[1ex]
     &&  \\[1ex]
     && 
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

The above comes from adapting the last code from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591858/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you desiring to delete horizontal or vertical space.  Not clear from your question.

Comment: also what do you want to accomplish with `p{-20cm}` you can not have a parbox with a negative `\hsize` for linebreaking.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The horizontal space. The space after the ":" and the line.

Comment: just replace Yp{-20cm}  by l  and replace && by &

Comment: I've been using latex for 30 years and I think that's the first time I have ever seen a p column with a negative specified width:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something more like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}


 
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lY}
    name:& name\\[-2ex]
    & \hrulefill \\[1ex]
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.

Comment: What does the `l` stands for? and why the double & had to be changed to one?

Comment: @Verónica it is a standard tabular column:  `l` for left aligned ( along with `c` for center and `r` for right)

Comment: You had three columns two Y columns (so forcing the two name columns to have the same width and an unused p column in between) so you had to have `name & & name` to get the words into the Y columns,  I just have two columns so you just need `name & name` @Verónica

Comment: got it, double thanks:)