# Tabular contents shifting to left. How do I center it?

Tags: tables, width, center

When I make the table `\columnwidth`, everything shifts to the left.

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|c||c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline
    A & B & C & D & E \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

How can I center it in the simplest way, **without using absolute width**?

[image]

Comment: use `tabular` not `tabularx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) has said, using a `tabular` environment can put contents at the center.

Since you are already using `tabularx`, I assume you want the contents to fill the column width, so it should be based on the `X` column type, but with a little modification to make it centered (as is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932/234654))

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered X
```

Therefore, it is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|Y||Y|Y|Y|Y|}
    \hline
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline
    A & B & C & D & E \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

> By the way, when asking a question, it would be better if you provide a full minimum working example (MWE) from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.