# New line in column environment

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, itemize, columns

I am trying to use \newline in the columns environment but it doesn't seem to work. This is the minimum working code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.46\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item bloop
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,hbox]
                \scriptsize\texttt{line1}
                \scriptsize\texttt{line2}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to get "line1" and "line2" in two separate lines. Could you please give me a hint on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your issue is not related to the use of the `columns` environment but more related to the `tcolorbox` environment in which the two lines are placed.

Comment: Is this specific to beamer class? Because I have used \newline in a latex article class and it worked fine for me.

Comment: No. This is not specific to the `beamer` documentclass beut definitely caused by the `hbox` option of your `tcolorbox` environment. Regarding the use of `\newline`: In a normal document there should almost nerver be the need to explicitly use `\newline`.

Comment: unrelated but you have made your columns wider than `\textwidth` which may well make them fail to be projected if you present this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two different possibilities:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{empty line between "line 1"  and "line 2" and without hbox}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.46\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item bloop
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
                \scriptsize\ttfamily line1
                
                line2
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{with hbox and a tabular environment}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.46\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item bloop
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,hbox]
                \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scriptsize\ttfamily}l@{}}
                  line1 \\                
                  line2
                \end{tabular}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome response. Could you point me to where I can read about the options you used in the tabular environment ?

Comment: `@{}` removes the small horizontal white space that is added between the start of a column and the start of the text inside of this column. See also [clarification on the use of @{} with table headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1290/134144). `>{...}` can be used to insert come code that is added before every cell in this specific column. I added `\scriptsize` and `\ttfamily` here in order to avoid repeating `\scriptsize\texttt{...}` for both rows. Using `>{...}` needs the `array` package which I added to the preamble.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.